# C# Linq nearest index of a target element

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to create linq to find nearest index of a target element in C# 4.0?
Example, I have an array

```
string[] array=new string[] 
{"","","source","","source2","","","destination","source3","destination"};
```

the "destination" is found at 7 and 9, the nearest index of "destination" to 2 ("source") should be 7,not 9.

The current solution I know using if condition is,

```
int index(int sourceIndex,string[] array,string destination)
{
    int temp=sourceIndex;
    while(temp<array.Length)
    {
        if(array[sourceIndex]==destination)
            return sourceIndex;
        temp++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Edited To Add:
I need to find the destination In the increasing order in the forward direction
My main question being, find nearest index of a target element in an array in forward direction.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the role of `source` in the result? anyway you are asking us to write code for you, Normally SO will not provide code writing services. consider this as a gentle reminder

Comment: Do you really need to use Linq for this?

Comment: which would you prefer if you were looking for the nearest "destination" to "source3"?

Comment: is there the possibility of more than one "source" in the array?

Comment: @RufusL Source index is known and nearest in the forward direction , if there is no occurence, it need not return

Comment: `var index = Array.IndexOf(items, "destination", Array.IndexOf(items, "source"));`

Comment: @noviceinDotNet: could you please clarify if destination must appear after source or if you want to find it also if it's index is lower than the source-index?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Destination must appear after source. and I need to create a column in a datatable with around 50 entries. the entries have ttime as column names with 1 hour difference , 0080AM,0090AM,.. 0800PM , I am about to find the destination from the current time and update it into the new column, I need to do this every 15 minutes, I need the fastest way of finding the destination, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you actually have an array, I don't think you need to use Linq for this.

It would be much simpler to do this:

```
int startIndex = 2;
int nearest = Array.IndexOf(array, "destination", startIndex+1);
```

Then `nearest` will contain the result you're looking for, or -1 if `"destination"` can't be found.

Note: this only finds the nearest in the forward direction, which I assume is what you want given your statement: *"Source index is known and nearest in the forward direction , if there is no occurence, it need not return"*

Also note that I used `startIndex+1` because we don't need to start searching at the first position.

Comment: OP hasn't said that the start index must be after the index of `source`. What if there is a destination before source and one behind?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I believe he has said that in the comments - "nearest in the forward direction"

Comment: Is the method faster than Linq? I have situation to calculate it for a number of data , around 50,  inside a datatable and create a new column for it and update it. Thanks

Comment: @noviceinDotNet To determine if it is faster, you should time it carefully, but I'd be very surprised if this wasn't significantly faster than the Linq approach. However, Linq to SQL may be able to perform the operation in SQL which may make it faster for that case - like I say, you'll have to time it.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily the most efficient solution, but if you don't expect a lot of matches it should work:

```
string[] array = new string[] {"","","source","","source2","","","destination","source3","destination"};
var withIndex = array.Select((Value, Index) => new { Index, Value });
var result = 
    (from dest in withIndex.Where(_ => _.Value == "destination")
    from source in withIndex.Where(_ => _.Value == "source")
    let dif = dest.Index - source.Index
    orderby dif
    select dest.Index)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

We first the occurrences of `source` and `destination` and we the find the smallest difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to use linq for this (say you have `IEnumerable` and not really an array), you can do it like this:

```
static int index(int sourceIndex, IEnumerable<string> array, string destination)
{
    return array
        // convert items stream into (item, index) pair
        .Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, Index = index })
        // skip items until condition is met
        .SkipWhile(c => c.Index <= sourceIndex || c.Item != destination)
        // we need index only
        .Select(c => c.Index)
        // if we found nothing - return -1
        .DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
        .First();            
}
```

If you have an array - please don't do this and use Matthew Watson answer.